# Which steps are involved in sentiment analysis with Huggingface Transformers?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, sentiment-analysis, huggingface

I want to perform a sentiment analysis of a dataset of (Spanish) tweets about COVID-19 vaccines.

I've already scraped the tweets and identified a [pretrained model](https://huggingface.co/finiteautomata/beto-sentiment-analysis) I can use for Spanish.

What I don't really understand - and don't seem to find the right resources either - is 
 *what steps are involved in the whole process?*

I know I have to fine-tune the model which I'm not exactly sure how to do. 
*Do I necessarily need a labeled dataset for this or can I just train the model on my scraped tweets (that don't have a label yet)?*

Comment: The pretrained model you linked does not work (at least not directly) for sentiment analysis since it is specifically for question answering.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
I just corrected it.